# debug multiple http requests with netbeans and glassfish

Tags: debugging, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I am using glassfish for my Java EE 7 JSF and EJB project, and netbeans as IDE.
I can debug http requests with breakpoints, in both the managed beans (jsf) and the ejbs.

But now I want to debug two http requests and I don't figure it out. currently when I open the jsf page in the browser twice, netbeans will debug only the first request, and will not show the breakpoints of the second until the first one is completely done.

So how can I debug two http listeners thread ?